# Getting a single variable from a cookie value stored in a JSON array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, cookies

Can you tell me how to pass one variable to JavaScript stored in the JSON array of the qookie file value?

Qookie is written this way:

```php
<?php
$cookie_key = 'count';
CookieManager::store($cookie_key, json_encode(array(
    'SameSite' => 'None',
         ...
    'lastvisit' => $time,
    'token' => $counts->token)));
```

The code example below outputs an entire array from qookie, while of all, only one token variable is needed to pass it alone to JavaScript:

```
function getCookie(count) {
    var matches = document.cookie.match(new RegExp("(?:^|; )" + count.replace(/([\.$?*|{}\(\)\[\]\\\/\+^])/g, '\\$1') + "=([^;]*)"));
    return matches ? decodeURIComponent(matches[1]) : undefined;
}
 
console.log(getCookie('count'));
```

But how to allocate only one token for JavaScript

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5v2Ud.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/28pLi.png)

Comment: [Please update your question and translate into English.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/non-english-questions)

Comment: What's your expected result? I'm not sure what you mean by "pass one variable to Javascript..."

Comment: Don't post text as images. Type the text.

Comment: The Qookie file contains the 'count' key, value: a JSON array with variables. From this array, it is necessary for JS to pass one variable "token"

Comment: The task is to pass a variable from PHP to a JS script on one page, to avoid inserting php-code to JS: <?php $token; ?>, and don't post it on the page itself. I think the most appropriate solution is to get the 'token' value from the JSON array Qookie

Comment: Is it JSON, an array, or an Object? JSON is a string. One of your screenshots is displaying an Object, with which you could simply use `Object.key`.

Comment: `JSON.parse()`, then treat as an object.

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)?

Comment: You are expected to put in some effort too; SO isn't a code-writing service. But say `theCookieJSON` is the variable your JSON is in, `const cookieObj = JSON.parse(theCookieJSON); const myToken = cookieObj.token;`

Answer (score -1):

```
<script>
function getCookie(count) {
    var matches = document.cookie.match(new RegExp("(?:^|; )" + count.replace(/([\.$?*|{}\(\)\[\]\\\/\+^])/g, '\\$1') + "=([^;]*)"));
    return matches ? decodeURIComponent(matches[1]) : undefined;
}

const cookieObj = JSON.parse(getCookie('count'));
const token = cookieObj.token;

console.log('My token: ' +token)
</script>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).